# How to ...... hide columns of a CxGrid with drag and drop

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe, tcxgrid, mvcxgridview

How to popup a customization dialog to hide columns, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"To achieve the desired result, set the GridView's OptionsCustomize.ColumnQuickCustomization property to True. Once it is done, you will notice a small button on the left of the column headers area. When you click it, a list of columns will be shown."

Source: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/q324077/tcxgrid-list-of-columns-to-hide-unhide

Comment: thanks i found it

Answer (score 1):

**.Controller.Customization := True;**